# What happened to neo-dogs?

Tags: uplift-universe

In David Brin's *Uplift Universe* humans are given patron status because they had already uplifted chimps and dolphins at the time of contact with Galactic Society.  But in *Sundiver*, mention is also made of neo-dogs.  They are never mentioned again.  Or at least, not in the second trilogy that I just finished re-reading (except as "dogs" humanity's loyal companion pet).

I remember vaguely reading, maybe in *The Uplift War*, that the older patron lines had blocked humanity from uplifting more of Earth's presentient species.  But I don't remember any mention of what befell the partially uplifted dogs.  Is this explained anywhere?

Comment: The "prevented humanity from uplifting further species" bit is a central plot element in the *The Uplift War*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This short story](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907183004/http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/1932093041/1932093041___1.htm) by David Brin mentions the eventual fate of neo-dogs in passing:

> Next came the habitat of talking neo-dogs, a breed that had been under modification for centuries, and recently, at long last, had mastered the deep mystery of door knobs, only to discover that the devices were being replaced in most homes by galactic technology psionic clasps. That tragic irony appeared to have broken the species' collective spirit. Mostly, neo-dogs just lay around nowadays, whining, licking themselves, and snapping vicious, Chestertonian insults at the ankles of anyone who unwarily passed close.

Humanity itself was prevented from uplifting any more species by the older lineages, and it seems like none of the patron lines wanted to pick up a broken, dispirited client.

Comment: Is 'Gorilla Dreams' considered canon to the Uplift universe? The irreverant style is strikingly different to the main novels, the locomotion methods are never mentioned again and the Alliances queuing to attack Earth are different from those mentioned in the novels. And that's just stuff in the first few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Also in Uplift War - Fiben complains that humans should have uplifted dogs instead of Neo-Chims because dogs would have been happy to fetch 'this n' that' for them and he could have been relaxing up in a tree.  This implies that the neo-dogs were forgotten, either by the author (I doubt it, but it could have been rewritten for continuity) or Earthclan.

Answer (score -1):

Brin stuck with the very snarky doorknob answer when I asked him about this on l-brin in 2007. I think that he just doesn't like dogs. Certainly neodogs might be given squirrel paws to offset this problem, though they might spend more time chasing their own tails.

Comment: What's "the very snarky doorknob answer"? A response from David Brin himself would be a very useful addition to this post, but you do need to be a bit more clear about what you mean.